# useContext(TableContext) returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Within a Material UI Table I would like to read from the TableContext ([Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a4972c5931e637611f6421ed2a5cc3f78207cbb2/packages/material-ui/src/Table/TableContext.js)), which should be set by the Table component ([Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a4972c5931e637611f6421ed2a5cc3f78207cbb2/packages/material-ui/src/Table/Table.js)). However:

```
const table = useContext(TableContext);
```

will always be undefined when done within a child component of Table.

[Reproduction on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-tdd-g2kb4?file=/demo.tsx) (check console.log output)

Manually Adding another TableContext into the component Tree "solves" this issue. But I'm really puzzled as to why this won't work out of the box...