# Material ui TableContext returns "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the TableContext to check what the current size is, inside a subcomponent. However, I'm struggling to get anything but `undefined`:

```js
    const Bar = () => {
        const tableContext = React.useContext(TableContext)
        const tableContextLvl2 = React.useContext(Tablelvl2Context)
        console.log(tableContext) // logs "undefined"
        console.log(tableContextLvl2) // logs "undefined"
        return <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
                hello
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    }
    
    export const Foo = () => {
        return (
            <TableContainer>
                <Table>
                    <TableBody>
                        <Bar />
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        )
    }
```

What am I missing here? When checking out the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/Table/Table.js#L47), it looks like `<Table>` provides a context to it's child components, so would expect to get something.

I'm using material-ui version 4.11.3.

Comment: I see this has been asked already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078662/usecontexttablecontext-returns-undefined

Answer (score 0):

[image: Internal component]

TableContext is not exposed to be used directly.

To get the size of `Table` I suggest to use a state that gets incremented each time you add a row or column.

Or if you want to create a pagination on `Table` you can get there the `count`

https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/

Comment: I see. I don't want the number of items in the table, I simply want the "size" that is part of the TableContext, i.e. the size as described here: https://material-ui.com/api/table/ which configures if the table should be dense or not

Comment: @simen-andresen you need size as string, like `'small'
| 'medium'` ?

If this is the case, the you can use a intermediary variable that will hold that value and can be passed down to components as props or new context.

`const tableSize = 'small';

<Table size={tableSize}>
    <Component tableSize={tableSize} />
</Table>`

Comment: yep! Any idea how to get it without explicitly passing it through as props?

Comment: I've edited my answer above while guessing for you answer. So, props drill or context that holds that value.

Comment: I know I can pass it through as props, but I was hoping to avoid having to do this. We're having quite a complicated table hierarchy, and having to pass props into every component in the Table's subtree gives a lot of prop drilling. Using context here would just a much better solution

Comment: @simen-andresen Yes, just create your own context and if you have alot of context providers in your project check out my article about this: https://dev.to/sincovschi/react-flat-multi-providers-1142

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231511/discussion-between-eugene-and-simen-andresen).

Comment: @simen-andresen, hey, give a thumb up or accept if my answer was useful. Thanks :)